# cannot create Opportunity as other User in Apex anonymous code

Tags: apex, execute-anonymous

I am trying to create an Opportunity in an Apex anonymous code block, but
when I try and create it as another user, it does not complain, but it does
not "stick" either... iow, it ends up being owned by me.

```
    String salesOwner = 'Earl Boffo';

    String ownerName = salesOwner;

    User oppOwner = [SELECT ID from User where Name =: ownerName];

   List<Opportunity> oppList = new List<Opportunity>();

    Integer j = 0;


    for (j = 0; j < maxOpps; j++) {
      String name = 'name' + j.format();
      String stageName = 'Qualified Opportunity';
      Date closeDate = system.today();
      String oppType = 'New';

      System.debug('(apex_create_opp_anon) Creating Oppty as owner: ' + ownerName + ', Id: ' + oppOwner.Id);

      Opportunity opportunity =  new Opportunity(Name=name,AccountId=accountList[0].Id,StageName=stageName,   
              CloseDate=closeDate, Type=oppType, Owner=oppOwner);

      oppList.add(opportunity);
    }

    insert oppList;
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I have tons of test cases, and need to be able to quickly create
Opportunities as if they were created by various users.

Thanks,

Mitch

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out... I was doing it incorrectly.. this worked:

```
eachAccount.OwnerId = oppOwner.Id;

Opportunity opportunity =  new Opportunity(Opp_Name_Tag__c=name,AccountId=accountList[0].Id,StageName=stageName,   
              CloseDate=closeDate, Type=oppType, OwnerId=oppOwner.Id);
```